# No Chart Title Error Immediately After Setting A Title

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm making a macro that generates bar charts.  I've run this code on two computers.  It works fine on one computer.  The other generates a "This object has no title" error.

The thing is, the line above it declares it to have one.  If I go up one line and restart the code at the declaration, it continues on just fine.  It even creates 2 more charts just like it using identical code (copy pasted from this one with subtle renames) that's just retailored for the similar data in other columns and does so with no errors.

The best stopgap I can think to do is put an error check and loop it back up to run again, but that doesn't explain the behavior.

The section in question looks like this:

```
WsDBar.HasTitle = True
WsDBar.ChartTitle.Text = "Phase-A Error Breakdown"
```

Any thoughts on why/how it's failing to update to have a title and how to fix it?

Edit with more code:

```
WsDBar.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

WsDBar.SetSourceData Source:=DBarData

For i = 1 To 5
If WsDBar.FullSeriesCollection.Count < 5 Then WsDBar.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
If WsDBar.FullSeriesCollection.Count > 5 Then WsDBar.SeriesCollection(6).Delete
WsDBar.FullSeriesCollection(i).name = WsCD.Cells(2, i + 8).Value
WsDBar.FullSeriesCollection(i).Values = WsCD.Range(WsCD.Cells(3, i + 8), WsCD.Cells(RowCountCD, i + 8))
WsDBar.FullSeriesCollection(i).XValues = WsCD.Range("A3:A" & RowCountCD)
WsDBar.FullSeriesCollection(i).Interior.ColorIndex = (i + 41)
Next
```

What I did that works is turning the broken area into this:

```
ReloopD:
On Error Resume Next

WsDBar.HasTitle = True
If WsDBar.HasTitle = False Then
    LoopCount = LoopCount + 1
    If LoopCount > 100 Then Stop
    GoTo ReloopD
End If
WsDBar.ChartTitle.Text = "Phase-A Error Breakdown"
'y-axis name
WsDBar.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
If WsDBar.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False Then
    LoopCount = LoopCount + 1
    If LoopCount > 100 Then Stop
    GoTo ReloopD
End If
WsDBar.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "# of Items"
```

I need to try the other options I was given.  Thanks!

Comment: Can we see more of the surrounding code please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WsDBar.ChartTitle.Caption = "Phase-A System Error Breakdown"
```

rather than

```
WsDBar.ChartTitle.Text= "Phase-A System Error Breakdown"
```

Comment: If it's caused by a VBA timing issue, calling it Caption or Text won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes VBA isn't finished with one operation before attempting the next. It may have started adding the title, but perhaps the title's textbox isn't ready to accept anything yet, so the second line crashes.

You can insert `DoEvents`, which tells VBA to wait until Windows has taken care of all the stuff it's in charge of.

```
WsDBar.HasTitle = True
DoEvents
WsDBar.ChartTitle.Text = "Phase-A System Error Breakdown"
```

**Edit:** Sometimes one `DoEvents` isn't enough. The following loops through the offending statement until the error doesn't happen:

```
WsDBar.HasTitle = True
Do
  DoEvents
  Err.Clear
  On Error Resume Next
  WsDBar.ChartTitle.Text = "Phase-A System Error Breakdown"
  If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Do
Loop
On Error GoTo 0
```